# Return valus from Python file to HTML buy press submit button?

Tags: python, html

I got a home page with parameters that the user (client) enter to forms. (File named `page2.htm`)

In addition, I got a `new_1.py` file, that contains one big function, that run by 4 parameters.

What I want, is to communicate between all files. What means that when I press the `submit` button on `page2.htm`, all 4 parameters will sent to `new_1.py` file, and the Python function will return the values to HTML, for example: `page3.htm`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using a Python Web Framework?

Comment: What it means ?I allready have a domain and web-host

Comment: It's _possible_ to do this using the Python [cgi](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) module, but there are more modern ways to do this. OTOH, old-fashioned CGI may be adequate for your needs if your site is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some web microframework like Bottle or Flask.
Using Bottle your page2.html you will have:

```
<form action="/update" method="POST">
  <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="par_1"><br />
  <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="par_2"><br />
  <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="par_3"><br />
  <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="par_4"><br />
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
</form>
```

Your page3.html will be:

```
<p>
  par_1: {{par_1}}    
  par_2: {{par_2}}
  par_3: {{par_3}}    
  par_4: {{par_4}}
</p>
```

In your new_1.py you will make a GET method to show you the form:

```
@route('/')
def index():
    return template('page2')
```

And a POST method that the form is calling in `/update` route:

```
@route('/update', method='POST')
def update():
    val1 = request.forms.get('par_1')
    val2 = request.forms.get('par_2')
    val3 = request.forms.get('par_3')
    val4 = request.forms.get('par_4')
    # Do something
    return template('page3', par_1=val1, par_2=val2, par_3=val3, par_4=val4)
```

You will then go to `localhost:8080` to see the form.

For more on how to setup Bottle go to http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html

Note that Bottle uses .tpl (template) extension instead of .html. I think it will work fine with .html, but if not, change your htmls to .tpl

Comment: it looks good , i  really want to send 4 parameters from page2.htm to new_1.py but i want the python function will return parameters that on new_1.py file. and not the same 4 ...

Comment: In the post method you can do whatever you want with those 4 parameters. I made it return the same 4 just to show an usage example. You can pass any value to your html on the template() method

Comment: but, i don't need a server.py file ?

Comment: In this case, new_1.py is the server folder. Take a look on how Bottle works and it will became clear. Its very easy

Comment: i did all things that you told me but i got an error :  405 Method Not Allowed. do you know what to do ?

Comment: @OhadMezan Sounds like a mismatch between the HTTP request method between the form and the `route()` decorator. Do you have POST on both ends?

Comment: The problem was that you were calling '/update' on the browser, not a default '/' route to show you the forms. I have edited the post so you can fix the error

Comment: Still the same problem :( I don't know what to do... tell me if i do somthing wrong... i'm edit my new_1.py file like you wrote, but in the end add run(host='localhost', port=8080). then the server is running but when i open the browser and go to this addres, i cant see nothing, error 500. when i try to add /update , i got a 405 error again - method not allowed.

Comment: Error 500 is server error, and should appear on the console, what error is it?